# Can't switch states - flash builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, state

I made a form for users to register.
Now my problem is when the user fills in the correct information and he presses the button submit the states won't change.

```
[Bindable]
        private var validatorArr:Array;

        private function init():void {
            validatorArr = new Array();
            validatorArr.push(Name_stringValidator);
            validatorArr.push(Surname_stringValidator);
            validatorArr.push(email_emailValidator);
            validatorArr.push(Homeadress_stringValidator);
            validatorArr.push(homeCity_stringValidator);
            validatorArr.push(Postcode_NumberValidator);
        }

        private function validateForm(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            var validatorErrorArray:Array = Validator.validateAll(validatorArr);;
            var isValidForm:Boolean = validatorErrorArray.length == 0;
            if (isValidForm) {
                this.currentState = "Shoppingstate";

            } else {
                this.currentState="Loginstate";
            }
        }
```

I have no errors. But after filling in the form the Loginstate will not change to Shoppingstate.

Comment: put a breakpoint or trace and look at validatorErrorArray.length. If your conditional isn't passing then one of the validators must be reporting invalid data. If you are 100% sure that isValidForm is being set to true, then I would look at scope.  Like maybe it should read this.myCart.currentState.  Just making suggestions since I don't see anything glaringly "wrong" with that code.

Comment: Thx for the help there was a problem with one of the validators. I have deleted it and now it works.

Comment: @MunlauYau Please answer your own question then, if you already have the solution.